# Video won't fill the width of the container

Tags: html, css, video, fullscreen

As you can see in the image I provided the video is not full width, I want it to fit the rest of the container. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, here is the image:
[Image of the div and video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeSt1.png)

The code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="content-2">
     <div class="fullscreen_bg"> 
     <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg_video">
            <source src="images/Ajvar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video></div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
.content-2 {

height: 350px;
overflow: hidden; }

.fullscreen-bg {

max-height:350px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
padding:0;
margin:0;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
z-index: -1000;
overflow:hidden;}


.fullscreen-bg__video {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover;
overflow: hidden;}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
 .fullscreen-bg__video {
   height: 300%;
   top: -100%;
       }
      }

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
  .fullscreen-bg__video {
   width: 300%;
   left: -100%;
     }
   }
```

Comment: put your video tag inside of the div fullscreen_bg

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did it but still the same thing :/

Answer (score 0):

Try width attribute for video tag:

```
<video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg_video" width="350" height="350">
    <source src="images/Ajvar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: <video loop muted autoplay poster="img/videoframe.jpg" class="fullscreen-bg_video" width="350" height="350">
            <source src="images/Ajvar.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>

Comment: It would be better, you post the formatted code within your answer, instead of in comment.